# What is the difference between CANPA and CDFA?

Tags: commercial-aviation, general-aviation, pilots, non-precision-approach, instrument-approaches

What is the difference between Constant Angle Non-Precision Approach (CANPA) and continuous descent final approach (CDFA)?

Comment: CANPA and CDFA are two identical terms.  CANPA was originally used, and it was replaced with CDFA per ICAO standards.